# Visual Studio HTML Designer Split Views Vertically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem with the Visual Studio IDE where in my Tools >> Options >> HTML Designer, the Split Views Vertically is unchecked, yet the IDE decides to still keep the aspx page and source code split vertically. Anyone know how I can fix this? Must be a registry key somewhere that I can delete.

I've tried resetting the Window Layout by going to Window >> Reset Window Layout, and also trying Tools >> Import/Export Settings >> Reset All Settings.

The current settings is NOT checked, which means the windows should split horizontally (the default settings). This problem exists and occurred the same way for my Visual Studio 2010 installation, and now exists for my Visual Studio 2012 installation. Both IDE settings are not set to vertically split, but yet still split vertically.

I hope this isn't too confusing. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem, restarting VS and the computer fixed it magically!!

Comment: my computer has been restarted many times since this happened. It's been about a month now. Still occurring. Any other ideas?